# CloudFront efficient for millions of static images that are rarely seen multiple times?

Tags: static, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website with millions of images hosted on Amazon S3 (Big database of items). Images are rarely seen multiple times. Would it be efficient or worth it to go through CloudFront? I understand the images expire after a set time so if no one views it in that set time it's pointless is it not? Does it cost money on the initial CloudFront to S3 request? If not, then I should just have it on anyways?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your origin server (the original copy) is not on an AWS resource, it will cost money to cache it on CloudFront. But since the images are on S3, this will be free (effective December 1, 2014). S3 data transfer to Cloudfront is free as well.

If the images are not likely to be seen more than once, it doesnt make sense to store it on CloudFront. Storing them on CloudFront will only make sense if it receives more than 1 views within the set TTL.

But since this is going to be free, it is okay to cache it on CloudFront and serve it from there. Though this is unlikely to increase the user experience or image load times for you.